# how to print a string in python 1000 time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and I came across this interesting question which says:

Implement a generator cycle such that if we assign

```
y = cycle()
```

then repeated calls to

```
next(y)
```

return the values

```
food

pizza

hungry

food

pizza

hungry
```

In an endless cycle. If it can’t manage an endless cycle, then do 1000 cycles then stops.

Using loop is not allowed I can use something called a stream (infinite list).

How can I do this?

Comment: @hansolo  can u please show it as an answer and use def ? that will be much understandable

Comment: `Implement a generator` - here's your answer. Read about generators and `yield` keyword.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. You're more likely to get a response if you detail what steps you took to try to find a solution.  Please see the Stack Overflow Question Guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TASO could you kindly stop deleting all the question and context? It substantially detracts from readability and understandability

Comment: @LukasThaler Seems like OP did that with another question yesterday - it was put on hold afterwards as "not clear"...

Comment: Edited it back. (Sorry it's not a rollback, I noticed the button after I already manually pasted the content.)

Answer (score 3):

the trick is to wrap three `yield` statements into an endless loop. That way, they'll be cycled indefinitely

```
def cycle():
    while True:
        yield 'food'
        yield 'pizza'
        yield 'hungry'
```

To print the first 1000 iterations, use

```
y = cycle()
for i in range(1000):
    print(next(y))
```

Comment: can u show as a code pleas ?

Comment: then how to test it ?

Comment: like is it gonna print 1000 times?

Comment: `y = cycle()` and then call `next(y)` as many times as you want. You can use a `for loop` to do this as in `for i in range(1000): print(next(y)`

Comment: can u edit ur code above and add it

Comment: that will be great for others to understand as well

Comment: cant it be added inside the mean function ?

Comment: That's not what the exercise asks you to do. You are supposed to implement a generator `y = cycle()` that yields the words when `next(y)` is called. Hence, I separated the implementation and calls into different blocks

Comment: Please don't write code for users if they don't provide their own. We're not here to do people's homework (or job) for them. We're here to help them _learn_ and providing code to blindly copy and paste doesn't help with that.

Comment: Yessir, will refrain from that in the future. Didn't actually know (or forgot) that was a guideline around here

Comment: It appears most of what was the question was deleted by the OP. I suggested an edit to restore the question and context

Comment: @LukasThaler I did not see that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> Implement a generator `cycle`

Do you know what is a generator? If not, read about generators and `yield` keyword.

Quick answer:

```
def cycle():
    my_list = ["food", "pizza", "hungry"]
    while True:
        yield from my_list
```

Output:

```
>>> y = cycle()
>>> next(y)
'food'
>>> next(y)
'pizza'
>>> next(y)
'hungry'
>>> next(y)
'food'
```

Comment: but i want to print it 20 times how can i achieve that ?

Comment: @h4ze  Neat way of yielding from a list. Learned something new today

Comment: @LukasThaler `yield from` is in Python since 3.3 or so. You can use it with any iterable, not only lists. :) This includes other generators!

Comment: @h4z3 how u can make it print 20 times ?

Comment: @TASO You wanted a generator. An infinite generator. That's why I said you should read what a generator is and how to use it. Generators are lazily evaluated iterable. If you want 20, you can do e.g. `for i in range(20): print(next(y))` - just like you would take 20 elements from a laaaarge list.